# Sound does not play the first time. Why?

Tags: audio, windows-phone-7, mediaelement

I  gave it a shot on WP7 forums @ MS and no one could help, so trying here.

I cooked up a simple app, that has a button. Upon clicking, it plays a sound with the MediaElement control.  When I click the button the first time, it does not play at all.  The second and subsequent times, it plays the sound fine.

The first time around, the MediaOpened event of the MediaElement if fired off, but the MediaEnded never fires.  The subsequent times, the events work as expected.

I posted a small project here documenting the issue.
http://www.angryhacker.com/toys/MediaElementTest.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close out the question.  Here are [comments](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/72086.aspx) by a dev on the WP7 team.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a bug with Native Media Library and is caused by

```
MediaPlayer.GameHasControl
```

When app has been loaded you could call button_click(null,null) with volume 0.0 - just a guess.

Do you want to play a music whole game or just something short like this one?
As a workaround use SoundEffect class.

Comment: Just short sounds here and there.  I basically implemented what you suggested a while and it worked, but it's just ugly.

Comment: Is it? u just make an instance of SoundEffect class, load the sound and just call the play method. BTW u don't need a lifetime object with XNA dispatcher. Just call Framework.Update() then sound.play()